# Using a parent directory as a Leiningen dependency?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am working on a Clojure library. Inside the library is an example app that shows how to use the library. In the example app, which is in a subdirectory, what is the cleanest way to depend on the parent library? I want this to be fast; I want the dependency always be in step with the current library code. That means avoiding deploying to Clojars (or elsewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Leiningen "Checkout" Dependencies](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

You can add "../src" to the :source-paths in project.clj

Since you always want the current version of the parent's code, and it will always be in the same relative place, it's less a "dependency" to be resolved and more a classpath to be used to find code.

Comment: There's also `.lein-classpath` if you don't want that info in the project.clj